# Altering Attribute in Struts2 Tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have the following code:

```
<s:textfield name="product.size" size="15" maxlength="15"></s:textfield>
```

Is it possible to change the value of product.size and add a suffix to it in the JSP itself?

If so, what would be the best approach?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The `value` attribute should be able to take an OGNL expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id to textfield and then change it's value via javascript or jquery:

```
<s:textfield name="product.size" id="productSize" size="15" maxlength="15"></s:textfield>
```

If you are familiar with jquery, you can do this:

```
$("#productSize").val($("#productSize").val() + "suffix");
```

And if you are not familiar with jquery, you can do this via javascript:

```
document.getElementById("productSize").value = document.getElementById("productSize").value + "suffix";
```